# updating a document using the $max operator on arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

i have the following document:

```
 {
    _id: 12,
    item: 'envelope',
    qty: ISODate("2021-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
    arrayField: [ 128, 190, 1 ]
  }
```

and i try to update it using this command

```
products> db.products.update({_id:12},{$max : { arrayField : [1,190,1879]} })
```

the output is as follows:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
```

I don't really understand how the comparison between the existing arrayField and the new one is being done. They are both Arrays, so there should be some kind of comparison on every element, but how exactly does it work?

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#std-label-faq-dev-compare-order-for-BSON-types) i read this:

> With arrays, a less-than comparison or an ascending sort compares the smallest element of arrays, and a greater-than comparison or a descending sort compares the largest element of the arrays. As such, when comparing a field whose value is a single-element array (e.g.  [1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#std-label-faq-dev-compare-order-for-BSON-types) ) with non-array fields (e.g. 2), the comparison is between 1 and 2. A comparison of an empty array (e.g. [ ]) treats the empty array as less than null or a missing field.

But i still don't understand exactly... Could someone provide an example in my case?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: The problem here is that i don't understand how the comparison works. Is the comparison made on every single element of the array? Are the elements rearranged before the comparison? I can easily say that 1879 is bigger than 190, but how does mongodb takes this information into account? I hope it helps with my question...

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB takes the min or max, to represent the array in comparisons, for the query operators.

**Numbers**

```
{"ar" : [1,2,3]}

(<= ar 1) => (<= min(1,2,3) 3) => (<= 1 3)  true
(>= ar 3) => (>= max(1,2,3) 3) => (<= 3 3) true

(= ar 2)  => true because it contains the element

For empty arrays either < or > its always false compared to a number
```

**Arrays**
(again take the min if < , or max it >)

```
{"ar" : [1,2,3]}

(<= ar [0 1 2 3]) false because its like min(ar)=1 <min(0,1,2,3)=0

(= ar [1]) false we need all elements =
```

**For the update $max operator**

```
if both are arrays => elements are compared one by one.

max [1 2 3] [5] => [5]
max [1 2] [1 2 -100] => [1 2 -100]
```

Those are only for the `$gte,$gt,$lt,$lte, $eq` **query** operators.
The aggregate ones with same names are strict and don't work like this.

*Its not like complete because we have many types,i think the above are ok, answer might help, it was big to fit in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, but i still don't understand it in my case. The first array in my example is [ 128, 190, 1 ], and the second is [1,190,1879]. max (128,190,1) = 190, and max(1,190,1879) = 1879. So the update should modify the document, since the provided array is > than the one already in the document. What am i missing?

Comment: you are not just missing, i was missing also, i tested now, i think `$max` it takes the elements one by one, and compares them. Those rules apply for `$max` only if different data types i think. i am sorry for the confusion. The above i think are working, but not for `$max`